# MYSQL: How to make composite unique constraint case insensitive

Tags: mysql, case-sensitive, unique-constraint, unique-key

Table Query:

```
CREATE TABLE `TESTING_TABLE` (
   `ID` char(36) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
   `NAME` char(36) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
   `DISPLAY_NAME` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
   UNIQUE KEY `DISPLAY_NAME_UK` (`NAME`,`DISPLAY_NAME`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

First row insert:

```
INSERT INTO `TESTING_TABLE` (`ID`, `NAME`, `DISPLAY_NAME`) VALUES ('1', 'Foo', 'Bar');
```

Second row insert:

```
INSERT INTO `TESTING_TABLE` (`ID`, `NAME`, `DISPLAY_NAME`) VALUES ('2', 'Foo', 'bar');
```

As I have 'DISPLAY_NAME_UK' unique constraint, I expect the second row insert should throw a "Duplicate entry" exception. But it is allowing case sensitive values in DISPLAY_NAME column. How to make it case insensitive?

Answer (score 2):

Replace utf8_bin with utf8_general_ci

```
CREATE TABLE `TESTING_TABLE` (
`ID` char(36) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`NAME` char(36) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`DISPLAY_NAME` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY `DISPLAY_NAME_UK` (`NAME`,`DISPLAY_NAME`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want "bar" and "Bar" to be treated as the same value, this isn't case sensitivity, it's case **insensitivity**.

The easiest approach would probably be to use a case-insensitive collation, like `utf8mb4`.

Comment: Getting exception - Error Code: 1273. Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4'

Comment: utf8mb4 is a character set name, not a collation name.